# Создание кластера на основе Glassfish

Tags: cluster, кластер, glassfish, ubuntu, сервер

Кто-нибудь создавал кластер на основе Glassfish? Хочу пока побаловаться - посмотреть, но не могу найти нормального руководства.

P.S. у меня mac и на virtualbox (ubuntu server 10.04).

Comment: Когда-то тоже хотел попробовать сие чудо, но бросил из-за того, что не нашел как реализовать. Тоже интересно было бы узнать.

Comment: @Sasha121 вот есть пример со второй версией http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5zB2xU6O44
но у меня пока не получилось..   интересно также было бы узнать как это реализовывется на практике..